# How to find 15% from big.Int

Tags: go, bigint

I'm want to get 15% of big.Int value, how can I do this?

```
new(big.Int).Mul(totalValue, new(big.Int).Div(new(big.Int).SetUint64(15), new(big.Int).SetUint64(100)))
```

returns 0

Comment: Integer division of `15/100` is going to be `0`. Do you need to do this using integer arithmetic, or are you expecting to get fractional values? You probably want to use a `Float` instead.

Comment: * Integer *multiplication* of `15/100` is going to be `0`

Answer (score 1):

Order of operations can be really important with integer arithmetic when division is involved. Take the following code for example

```cs
int n = 200;

Console.WriteLine($"{n * (15 / 100)}");
Console.WriteLine($"{(n * 15) / 100}");
```

The first WriteLine will print 0 and the second will print 30.
Even though both lines should theoretically yield the same result because multiplication and division are associative. And they would actually produce the same result if you were using floating point math.

However, in this case integer math works a little differently. The problem is 15/100 yields 0 with integer division. So if the division is performed first, the result will always be 0.

Comment: The would *probably* produce the same result in FP math - FP still has limited precision and rounding errors, its limitations are just different from integers.